# Select all elements between two nodes on same level

Tags: xml, xpath

```
...
<h>unique-1</h>
<a>data</a>
<b>data</b>
<a>data</a>
<h>unique-2</h>
...
```

I need all data between two `h` nodes. I can point to `h` node with `//h[.='unique-1']` but can't find reference how to select all nodes between `<h>unique-1</h>` and `<h>unique-2</h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath 2.0, you can use the `intersect` operator in conjunction with the `following-sibling` and `preceding-sibling` axes:

```
          //h[.='unique-1']/following-sibling::*
intersect //h[.='unique-2']/preceding-sibling::*
```

In XPath 1.0, you can simulate the `intersect` operator with a "[Kaysian intersection](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/xsl-list/2000-08/msg00355.html)":

```
//h[.='unique-1']/following-sibling::*[
  count(.|//h[.='unique-2']/preceding-sibling::*)
  = count(//h[.='unique-2']/preceding-sibling::*)
]
```